# Joomla background application

Tags: mobile, joomla, background, notifications, backend

I'm about to run into a new project and i am now wondering what the possibilities are.

I thought about joomla to create the frontend of the app where the users can enter all input they are asked to. There will be, also, a mobile app (android and ios) to allow users do the same from their devices.

The third part is where i am not sure and im asking for advice. I neeed a backgoud app, continiusly analyzing all the info stored in the db(joomla db). At some point (certain bussines rule or triggers), the app should do some tasks like: Modifying db, sending e-mails and sending notification messages to android/iOS devices.

I'd really like to hear your suggestions for this last point.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for send a mail and modifying the DB there is no problem.. all that you will do it at your server-side, for send notifications to android I think you might need an android app that will request permittions to do that.